# statically and dynamically scopes

Tags: dynamic, compiler-construction, static, scope

I'm working on this problem and I got the answers :

Statically:  20, 16

Dynamically: 20, 100

**is that correct?**

Consider the program below (in a Pascal like language).  What is the output of the 
language is statically scoped?  What is the output if the language is dynamically scoped?

```
Program main;
   x: integer;
procedure f1(z: integer)
begin 
       return z * x;
   end
procedure f2(z: integer)
      int x;
   begin
       x = 2;
       return f1(z)  * x;
   end

begin /* main program */
   x = 5;
print f1(4);
   print f2(4);
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [static vs dynamic scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422139/static-vs-dynamic-scope)

Comment: it's not a duplicate, it's a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try out both versions? Using Perl with static scope:

```
my $x = 5;
sub f1($) {
  my $z = shift;
  return $z * $x;
}
sub f2($) {
  my $z = shift;
  my $x = 2;
  return f1($z) * $x;
}
print f1(4), "\n";
print f2(4), "\n";
```

I get `20`, `40`. (`20` being `4 * 5`, `40` being `(4 * 5) * 2`.)

Replacing all the `my`s with `local`s to get dynamic scope, I get `20`, `16`. (`20` being `4 * 5`, `16` being `(4 * 2) * 2`.)

Unfortunately, since you only posted your conclusions, no explanation, I can't point out where you went wrong . . .